# HTTPS iframe inside a HTTPS page not working

Tags: iframe, https, github-pages, firebase-hosting, mixed-content

How can we use github pages embedded in an iframe correctly?

I've hosted a website in firebase and it is using a custom domain over https, for example, **https://www.example.com**.

This website uses react and other things, but for one route (the landing page one) I would like to use a static page hosted on github, for example **https://example.github.io/page**. So, to achieve this I've created an iframe inside the route **https://www.example.com/page**.

The problem is I've been receiving the following error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/page' was loaded
>   over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource
>   'http://example.github.io/page/'. This request has been blocked; the
>   content must be served over HTTPS.

The strange thing is the iframe looks correctly:

```
<iframe title="Page" src="https://example.github.io/page">unwanted text</iframe>
```

It is already using https, but looks like this is being ignored.
I already tried to use this meta `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">`, close the iframe with `</iframe>` and add an *unwanted text* inside the iframe.

Can we solve this?

Comment: Try adding a trailing slash to the iframe URL.

Comment: Wow, looks like it works =). I don't know why. Would you like post it as an answer?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you carefully examine your HTML code and the error message, you'll notice a slight difference in URLs besides the protocol part:

- `https://example.github.io/page`  - in the `iframe` `src` tag
- `http://example.github.io/page/` - in the error message

The reason could be that the URL https://example.github.io/page returns a *redirect* to the "canonical" version with the trailing slash (`/page/`), but a redirect URL must be a full URL, and the server for some reason isn't including the actual protocol in the redirect URL, always using `http://` instead. That could be due to configuration or coding at the server side (see also github issue [#289](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/289)).

As a workaround, use a URL that doesn't trigger the canonicalization redirect, i.e. `https://example.github.io/page/`.

Comment: This was my problem, too. If a redirect was happening, it wasn't clear from the request.